# R - Where is the `qr.lm` function

Tags: r, lm, predict

I'm tring to understand how does `predict.lm`function works in R. So, I type the name of the function in the console to see the code, copy the code to a new script and call pred to the new function:

```
pred <- function (object, newdata, se.fit = FALSE, scale = NULL, df = Inf,
      interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"), level = 0.95,
      type = c("response", "terms"), terms = NULL, na.action = na.pass,
      pred.var = res.var/weights, weights = 1, ...)
{

      <here goes the body of the predict.lm function which
       I do not copy to the post so it remains readable>

}
```

Then I fit a model to check that everything is ok and ask for a prediction using the new function `pred` which is a copy of `predict.lm` function:

```
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
new_obs = data.frame(Species = "versicolor")
print(pred(fit, newdata = new_obs, interval = "prediction"))
```

But then I got this error:

```
Error in pred(fit, newdata = newobs, interval = "prediction" :
  could not fund function "qr.lm"
```

I've searched for the function `qr.lm`, but I cannot find it. I only find the `qr` function.

Where is the `qr.lm` function and how can I access it?

Comment: perhaps of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this...

```
stats:::qr.lm
```

[`:::`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html) is how you access objects that are internal to a package.